Images are not loading on GitHub pages but are on Live Server
I recently learned how to code in HTML and I wanted to publish a website.  I used github pages because its free.  Since my project is more personal, I have a lot of "big" files so I used the provided 'GitLFS'. I checked that the website actually worked using Live Server, but when i uploaded it to github pages, Everything but the images loaded.>[Git Hub Pages] (https://i.sstatic.net/jCwnX5Fd.png)  [Live Server] (https://i.sstatic.net/M6T0qnzp.png)I might be going insane.  MY Code
I tried changing the file path but it didn't seem to work.  I have no clue how to fix it.

According to this comment in GitHub community using Git LFS in GitHub Pages is not supported.
You can use GitHub Actions instead to deploy your website with Git LFS files included.

There is no plans to support Git LFS in GitHub Pages. We actually
don't serve Pages' static assets from Git repositories.
Now that we support deploying Pages sites from Actions, "enabling LFS"
should be possible with:

Change your site's source from Branch to GitHub Actions in the settings

Pick a workflow from our starter workflows (we suggest them but they are also here)

Finally, update your workflow to update the actions/checkout step (example) to enable LFS


      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          lfs: true



Ah i see.. Thank you for showing me this!! I'll just find another way to use image files to it doesn't take up too much storage i guess
